# Is it possible to use Dependency Injection with xUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, ioc-container, xunit

I have a test class with a constructor that needs an IService.

```c#
public class ConsumerTests
{
    private readonly IService _service;
    public ConsumerTests(IService servie)
    {
      _service = service;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Should_()
    {
       //use _service
    }
}
```

I want to **plugin my DI container of choice** to build the **test class**.

Is this possible with **xUnit**?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. I have a lot of dependencies in my xUnit test, and it is not a proper solution to instantiate 30 dependencies by hand.

Comment: hi @MohammedNoureldin updated solutions below

Comment: This open source  project can help in leveraging Microsoft's DI in Xunit: https://github.com/Umplify/xunit-dependency-injection

Comment: Try this xunit di support built into xunit framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xunit.Di/

Answer (score 29):

Yes it's possible with Xunit.DependencyInjection

```
Install-Package Xunit.DependencyInjection
```

and you can inject your services

```cs
[assembly: TestFramework("Your.Test.Project.Startup", "AssemblyName")]
    
namespace Your.Test.Project
{
    public class Startup : DependencyInjectionTestFramework
    {
        public Startup(IMessageSink messageSink) : base(messageSink) { }
    
        protected override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IDependency, DependencyClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/pengweiqhca/Xunit.DependencyInjection

Comment: Note that this shows how v5 does it. Latest version (as of this writing) does it a little differently. See the linked documentation on github on how to do it now.

Comment: Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection uses the GPL license. But this answer uses a MIT licensed package. Very nice!

Answer (score 20):

Yes there is now, these two questions and answers should be consolidated in my opinion, see answer here

[Net Core: Execute All Dependency Injection in Xunit Test for AppService, Repository, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331395/net-core-execute-all-dependency-injection-in-xunit-test-for-appservice-reposit/57387120#57387120)

Use Custom Web Application Factory and ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService below, feel free to edit and optimize answer

**CustomWebApplicationFactory:**

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            var type = typeof(TStartup);
            var path = @"C:\\OriginalApplication";
    
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"{path}\\appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        });
    
        // if you want to override Physical database with in-memory database
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();
    
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("DBInMemoryTest");
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Integration Test:**

```cs
public class DepartmentAppServiceTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<OriginalApplication.Startup>>
{
    public CustomWebApplicationFactory<OriginalApplication.Startup> _factory;
    public DepartmentAppServiceTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<OriginalApplication.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ValidateDepartmentAppService()
    {      
        using (var scope = _factory.Server.Host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var departmentAppService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDepartmentAppService>();
            var dbtest = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDBContext>();
            dbtest.Department.Add(new Department { DepartmentId = 2, DepartmentCode = "123", DepartmentName = "ABC" });
            dbtest.SaveChanges();
            var departmentDto = await departmentAppService.GetDepartmentById(2);
            Assert.Equal("123", departmentDto.DepartmentCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://fullstackmark.com/post/20/painless-integration-testing-with-aspnet-core-web-api

Comment: Wow I haven't tried it yet, but I will vote it up as it seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: This works great for testing web projects, but can't be used for testing console applications.

Answer (score 9):

[This MIT-licensed library (developed by me)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) **(Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)** supports .NET 8.0 and brings in Microsoft's dependency injection container to Xunit by leveraging Xunit's fixture.

### Getting started

#### Nuget package

First add the following [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) to your Xunit project:

```
Install-Package Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

#### Setup your fixture

The abstract class of `Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Abstracts.TestBedFixture` contains the necessary functionalities to add services and configurations to Microsoft's dependency injection container. Your concrete test fixture class must derive from this abstract class and implement the following two abstract methods:

```cs
protected abstract IEnumerable<string> GetConfigurationFiles();
protected abstract void AddServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration);
```

`GetConfigurationFiles(...)` method returns a collection of the configuration files in your Xunit test project to the framework. `AddServices(...)` method must be used to wire up the implemented services.

#### Access the wired up services

There are two method that you can use to access the wired up service depending on your context:

```cs
public T GetScopedService<T>(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper);
public T GetService<T>(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper);
```

#### Adding custom logging provider

Test developers can add their own desired logger provider by overriding `AddLoggingProvider(...)` virtual method defined in `TestBedFixture` class.

#### Preparing Xunit test classes

Your Xunit test class must be derived from `Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Abstracts.TestBed<T>` class where `T` should be your fixture class derived from `TestBedFixture`.

Also, the test class should be decorated by the following attribute:

```cs
[CollectionDefinition("Dependency Injection")]
```

### Running tests in order

The library also has a bonus feature that simplifies running tests in order. The test class does not have to be derived from `TestBed<T>` class though and it can apply to all Xunit classes.

Decorate your Xunit test class with the following attribute and associate `TestOrder(...)` with `Fact` and `Theory`:

```cs
[TestCaseOrderer("Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.TestsOrder.TestPriorityOrderer", "Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection")]
```

### Examples

- Please [follow this link](https://github.com/Umplify/xunit-dependency-injection/tree/main/examples/Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.ExampleTests) to view a couple of examples on utilizing this library.
- [Digital Silo](https://digitalsilo.io/)'s unit tests and integration tests are using this library.

#### One more thing

Do not forget to include the following nuget packages to your Xunit project:

- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Options
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. But this virtual method does not exist in my version:

AddLoggingProvider(...)

What's the alternative?

Comment: Updating answer to include checking license. Install-Package Xunit.Microsoft.DependencyInjection is GPL licensed. Meaning we need to release the source code of any test and main project code we link to this project? Asking to be sure. Very awesome package otherwise

Comment: @TamusJRoyce I will change the GPL license.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce I changed the GPL license to MIT for this library. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Arash woot! Thank you! Make sure you get approval from anyone who has submitted fixes via code for your project. Otherwise, you will have violated the GPL (major issue with the GPL is contributions can lock those versions as gpl forever). You can rollback & change license

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this using nuget package out of this source code: https://github.com/dennisroche/xunit.ioc.autofac

It works great as long as you use `[Fact]`, but then I got blocked when started using `[Theory]`. There is a pull request to sort this out.

To unblock myself, I used CollectionFixture to inject Container and from the container, I resolve the Interface.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to test? The implementation of `IService` or the wiring of the DI container?

If you are testing `IService` implementations, you should be instantiating them directly in the test (and mocking any dependencies):

```
var service = new MyServiceImplementation(mockDependency1, mockDependency2, ...);
// execute service and do your asserts, probably checking mocks
```

If you are trying to test the wiring of the DI container, you need to reach out and grab the configured container explicitly. There is no "composition root" that will do that for you (pseudo-code follows, kind of Autofac flavored):

```
var myContainer = myCompositionRoot.GetContainer();
var service = myContainer.ResolveCompnent<IService>();
// execute service and do your asserts with the actual implementation
```

If you are using xUnit for running integration tests where you need to use the same object in multiple tests, look at Fixtures: https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context.

Answer (score 1):

There are other answers that are better for your question, but I wanted to show how we could do it without an IOC container using TheoryData.

Watch this:
Here's my interface

```
public interface IEpisodeManager
{
    Task<bool> Update(Episode episode);
    Task<bool> Set(IDictionary<string, IList<Episode>> creatorsToEpisodes);
    Task<Episode> GetById(string creatorId, int episodeId);
    Task<IEnumerable<Episode>> GetEpisodesByCreatorId(string creatorId);
}
```

Stay tuned, this is the test class:

1. What we're doing here is using the interface as the input parameter to the test.
2. Then creating a TheoryData object.  This can be initialized just like a list.  If you have dependencies and don't want nested constructor calls, just wrap this in a property.
3. Place a Theory and MemberData attribute on your test methods.

   public class EpisodeManagerTests
   {
   public static TheoryData EpisodeManager
   = new TheoryData()
   {
   new CreatorToKeysEpisodeManager(),
   new CreatorToEpisodeManager()
   };

   ```
    public EpisodeManagerTests()
    {
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(EpisodeManager), MemberType = typeof(EpisodeManagerTests))]
    public async Task GetById_ResponseProperlyMapped(IEpisodeManager manager)
    {
        var dict = EpisodeMock.CreatorToEpisodes;
        var setResult = await manager.Set(dict);
        Assert.True(setResult);

        var getResult = await manager.GetById("creator1", 2);
        Assert.NotNull(getResult);
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(EpisodeManager), MemberType = typeof(EpisodeManagerTests))]
    public async Task GetEpisodesByCreatorId_ResponseProperSize(IEpisodeManager manager)
    {
        var dict = EpisodeMock.CreatorToEpisodes;
        var setResult = await manager.Set(dict);
        Assert.True(setResult);

        var getResult = await manager.GetEpisodesByCreatorId("creator1");
        Assert.True(getResult.Count() == 4);
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(EpisodeManager), MemberType = typeof(EpisodeManagerTests))]
    public async Task GetEpisodesId_ResponseProperlyMapped(IEpisodeManager manager)
    {
        var dict = EpisodeMock.CreatorToEpisodes;
        var setResult = await manager.Set(dict);
        Assert.True(setResult);

        var getResult = await manager.GetById("creator1", 1);
        Assert.Equal(1, getResult.Id);
        Assert.Equal("creator1", getResult.CreatorId);
        Assert.Equal("filepath", getResult.FilePath);
        Assert.Equal("Casablanca", getResult.Name);
        Assert.Equal<TimeSpan>(TimeSpan.FromHours(4.99), getResult.RunningTime);
        Assert.Equal(DateTime.Parse("6/25/21"), getResult.AiredDate);
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(EpisodeManager), MemberType = typeof(EpisodeManagerTests))]
    public async Task Update_ResponseProperlyMapped(IEpisodeManager manager)
    {
        var dict = EpisodeMock.CreatorToEpisodes;
        var setResult = await manager.Set(dict);
        Assert.True(setResult);

        var updateRequest = new Episode()
        {
            AiredDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/21"),
            CreatorId = "creator1",
            FilePath = "filepath",
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Casablanca: The origin story",
            RunningTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(4.99)
        };

        var updateResult = await manager.Update(updateRequest);

        var getResult = await manager.GetById("creator1", 1);
        Assert.Equal(1, getResult.Id);
        Assert.Equal("creator1", getResult.CreatorId);
        Assert.Equal("filepath", getResult.FilePath);
        Assert.Equal("Casablanca: The origin story", getResult.Name);
        Assert.Equal<TimeSpan>(TimeSpan.FromHours(4.99), getResult.RunningTime);
        Assert.Equal(DateTime.Parse("6/25/21"), getResult.AiredDate);
    }
   ```

   }

This will write the tests for various implementations of your interface.

This likely isn't practical if you have several layers of dependencies, but if it's simple enough of a project, this is a super easy way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**xunit.di** is an extension of xUnit testing framework, built to support xUnit dependency injection, which allows us to achieve Inversion of Control (IoC) between test classes and their dependencies.

```
Install-Package Xunit.Di
```

**To use xunit.di:**

- Install the xunit.di nuget package
- Create a Setup.cs class, (optional) and inherits the Xunit.Di.Setup.cs
- Configure dependencies in the Setup.cs class.

Find instructions from [xunit.di GET-STARTED](https://github.com/clix455/Xunit.Di/blob/develop/GET-STARTED.md)

You need a **Setup.cs** class which configures **IServiceProvider**,

```
    public class Setup
    {
        private readonly IHostBuilder _defaultBuilder;
        private IServiceProvider _services;
        private bool _built = false;

        public Setup()
        {
            _defaultBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
        }

        public IServiceProvider Services => _services ?? Build();

        private IServiceProvider Build()
        {
            if (_built)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Build can only be called once.");
            _built = true;

            _defaultBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceImpl>();
                // where ServiceImpl implements IService
                // ... add other services when needed
            });

            _services = _defaultBuilder.Build().Services;
            return _services;
        }
    }
```

And your test class looks like below,

```
    public class ConsumerTests
    {
        private readonly IService _service;
        public ConsumerTests(IService servie)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Should_()
        {
            var result = _service.GetById("1");
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            //use _service
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes!

first: You can make an instance from *ServiceCollection* and call your *ConfigureServices* with this object from your stratup, then, use *BuildServiceProvider* to provide service, like below:

```
var myService = new ServiceCollection();
startup.ConfigureServices(myService);
Provider = myService.BuildServiceProvider();
```

I made a function call GetService to get services from provider like this:

```
protected T GetService<T>()
{
        return Provider.GetService<T>();
}
```

then I inject my services like this:

```
var myService = GetService<IRepository>();
```

hope help someone :)

Comment: This is not injection, but service location.

Comment: @Rookian , can u explain more? it injects the services so i can use it.

Comment: There are 3 injection possibilities. Method injection (method argument), Property Injection, and Constructor Injection. You are resolving a dependency within a method body. Typically what you want is to passively inject dependencies and not resolving them actively. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049940/service-locator-dependency-injection-and-container-and-inversion-of-control/10053413#10053413