# Unit Test: How to get a Configure class from the ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, startup

I am writing unit tests for my .Net Core 5 web application.  In the Startup.cs, I have 4 different calls similar to the following:

```
services.Configure<ServicesSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ServicesSettings"));
```

each injecting a different class.  I have tried the following:

```
ServicesSettings _serviceSettings = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ServicesSettings>();
Assert.NotNull(_serviceSettings);
```

but it returns null.  I am surprised that I could not find a similar question.  I tried to look at **ServiceCollection**, but could not find a method.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve. How to use configuration in a netcore unit test project or unit testing netcore configuration it self ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131219/is-it-possible-to-use-dependency-injection-with-xunit ?

Comment: Are you unit testing startup.cs code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get service for **IOptions**

```
IOptions<ServicesSettings> _serviceSettingOption = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<ServicesSettings>>();
_serviceSetting = _serviceSettingOption.Value;

Assert.NotNull(_serviceSetting);
```

I believe you are unit testing config injection capability/functionality, which is not required

Comment: Yes, I'm testing **Startup.cs**.